# c# excel 2007 print preview ribbon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

is it possible from c# to add some groups, buttons,... to excel-2007's print preview ribbon... why? i wanted to put some images on that ribbon so that user by selecting the image will be able to put it on a sheet (where ever on that sheet by dragging it) and print it with that sheet...
many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this the same way you add a group to any existing excel ribbon tab.

Create a VSTO add-in project and add a Ribbon XML class.

Inside the ribbon.xml file, this will give you a group with one button on the print preview tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabPrintPreview">
        <group id="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
          <button id="Test" label="Test"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

In order to find the names of all the built in tabs, groups and controls, check out this download

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4329D9E9-4D11-46A5-898D-23E4F331E9AE&displaylang=en

That will tell you what id's to use for the idMso (Microsoft Office id) attributes.

Here's a great place to get started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx

Check out the **Using Callbacks** section for info on how to handle button clicks.

Comment: thanks Dennis, how do i provide action for my button? i mean where... 
also how will i be able to insert an image on that previewed sheet?
thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: hi Dennis, is it possible to insert image with that button on that previewed sheet...? thanks in advance!

Comment: You really need to go to that MSDN getting started article. Come back here and ask questions if you don't understand something, but it's all in there.