# c# excel 2007 print preview sheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

how is it possible to (from c#) insert image on a sheet being displayed by print preview dialog? thanks a lot! assuming that i have my own button on a print preview ribbon which will insert the image.

this is actually continuation of my question 
[c# excel 2007 print preview ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160905/c-excel-2007-print-preview-ribbon) [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160905/c-excel-2007-print-preview-ribbon)

Answer (score 0):

so you want to know how to add an image dynamically to a office file, just prior to the print preview window being displayed? And i assume you then want the image removed once print/print preview is finished?

I'm pretty sure theres an event that fires, why not just use the Word OM (or Excel OM) to insert the image object into the header (or wherever else) once that event is fired?
not sure about an event that fires when the print preview is closed, as that would be the logical event to use to remove the image again. if this is what you want i will take a closer look at the events available.